# CRM 2011 objects LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to come up with the following query:

> Get me all the contacts who are simply connected to a certain account.

Here's what I have so far:

```
            var account = (Account)Context.Session["account"];
            var contacts = from ct in xrm.ContactSet
                              join cn in xrm.ConnectionSet
                              on ct.Id equals cn.Record2Id.Id
                              //&& cn.Record1Id.Id equals account.Id - can't really stick that there as per LINQ syntax standard...
                              select ct;
```

This obviously does not work, but I think it's obvious what I am trying to do.

Any ideas ?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I'm trying my best to entertain people here, sorry :)

Comment: FrancisDucharme, I did laugh at @EkoostikMartin's comment, but your question doesn't really help someone find this answer if they're having the same problem, which is what SO is all about.  Consider changing the question to more accurately describe the problem, and move the "Fun with Crm 2011 objects" to the description of the question.

Comment: @Daryl You're right. Done. I still think this was "fun" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the other side of the connection as the where clause

```
var contacts = from ct in xrm.ContactSet
               join cn in xrm.ConnectionSet on ct.Id equals cn.Record2Id.Id
               where cn.Record1Id.Id == account.Id
               select ct;
```

This will actually get both sides of any connection, where the Account and Contact are related any which way round

Comment: Brilliant, I wasn't that far off after all!